# How to send an email with a download link?

Tags: 7, webforms, emails, files

I had installed [Webform Protected Downloads](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_protected_downloads). But there are lot of things I don't like about this module:

1. Too many steps to download files.
2. The email's body content is only for plain text. You cannot use any HTML tag.

What options do I have to remedy these things I don't like?

Comment: Regarding #2, you can use [html mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlmail) or try steps provided in this [blog](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/html-emails-from-drupal-webform/).

Comment: @Yogesh, Thanks!!! Hope someone can help me solve number 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Functional Overview** of the [Webform Protected Downloads](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_protected_downloads) module seems to be like so (from its project page):

> This module provides protected downloads using webforms. When you create a webform you can select which of the attached files you want to protect. You need to specify the webform field used for the confirmation mail (this must be a mandatory email field) and how long the download should be accessible after the user has submitted the form.
>   When a user submits a webform with protected files he will be sent an email with a link to the downloads page. The link contains an individual hash code that will be checked upon page load to verify the access. If verification fails access will be denied. If it succeeds the user will see the default private upload file listing with all protected files that are attached to the webform.

Pretty sure you can build something similar (or close) by using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module instead, which integrates nicely with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) via the [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module. By using the Rules module you can, for example:

- Perfectly tune the entire content of your eMail to be sent. Have a look at these (working) [samples of **sending eMails** using Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A39516%20email%20rules%20%20requires%20%20label).
- Perform all sorts of redirects, based on the actual URL being used. Have a look at these (working) [samples of **performing redirects** using Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A39516%20redirect%20%20url%20rules%20%20requires%20%20label).

What else would you need?

## Video tutorials

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters.